# FastAPI + aiosqlite + AsyncSession - Exception closing connection

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi, aiosqlite

I'm using FastAPI, aiosqlite and SqlAlchemy. The application works fine, but I get this exception when I add a middleware.
The request returns 200 code, but then the exception is raised.
Do you have any suggestion?

Exception:

```
Exception closing connection <AdaptedConnection <Connection(Thread-1, started daemon 140230447978048)>>
```

Main file:

```py
from database import engine, Base, async_session
from dependencies import get_session, validate_authorization, validate_admin

from typing import List, Optional

app = FastAPI(title="Title", docs_url="/docs", redoc_url="/redocs", openapi_url=None)

@app.middleware("http")
async def verify_authorization(request: Request, call_next):
    token = request.headers.get('Authorization')
    #print(token, end="\n\n")
    #if not token or not validate_authorization(token):
    #    raise HTTPException(status_code=401, detail="Not valid authorization token.")
    response = await call_next(request)
    return response
```

database.py:

```py
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, declarative_base 
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import create_async_engine, AsyncSession


SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = "sqlite+aiosqlite:///./DB.db"
#SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = "postgresql+asyncpg://user:password@localhost/db"

engine = create_async_engine(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL, future=False, echo=False, connect_args={"check_same_thread": False})
async_session = sessionmaker(engine, expire_on_commit=False, class_=AsyncSession)
Base = declarative_base()
```

dependencies.py

```py
from fastapi import HTTPException
from sqlalchemy.exc import SQLAlchemyError
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import AsyncSession
from sqlalchemy import update, delete, select, insert

from typing import AsyncGenerator

from database import async_session


async def get_session() -> AsyncGenerator:
    async with async_session() as session:
        try:
            yield session
            await session.commit()
        except SQLAlchemyError as sql_ex:
            await session.rollback()
            raise sql_ex
        except HTTPException as http_ex:
            await session.rollback()
            raise http_ex
        finally:
            await session.close()
```